# XML error in android application

Tags: xml, android, layout

I added a new layout in the project and after adding it, I am getting error, even I deleted the layout file still error keep on coming, below is the screen shot for more explanation:
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/13ea6caf83.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/13ea6caf83.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: I suppose its an eclipse bug. 
Sometimes eclipse points out errors where there are none. Most times, it goes away when I make an inconsequential change and save it again. Sometimes it gets corrected when I delete project(not permanently) and import it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me too and I spent an half of working day to rid it away 
Hope it works for you too:

- Right click on the error line in the
  "Problems tab"
- Click on delete
- Refresh yuor project
- Hopes your error goes away

Answer (score 0):

In xml error Click the project menu it shows its navigation in that click clean it open alert dialog box click ok then rightclick the project then select build project it will be run. i hope so

Otherwise dont give newline in between line 1 and line 2

Try this ....................